# autoindent in vim for selected text

Tags: vim, indentation

1) Is there anyway to autoindent/retab on a set of lines, rather than the entire file?

```
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set tabstop=4
```

has been defined in my `.vimrc`.

What I want is to select a bunch of lines and apply indentation only on them. This is because the file is large and I just want to clean my line of codes. By doing `:retab`, I would have to force the whole file to be reindented.

For example select the following code and reindent automatically

```
def hello(self):
 line1
 line2
```

to

```
def hello(self)
    line1
    line2
```

2) Is there any way that I can reverse tab? Something like Shift-Tab in Eclipse. It goes back 4 spaces.

Comment: When you say you have set `shifttab=4`, I assume you mean `shiftwidth`? Vim does not have any `shifttab` setting.

Comment: Can you clarify if the example you have is one space or a tab? (SO doesn't distinguish between the two very well)

Comment: In the first its one space, and the second has 4 spaces ( 1 tab ).

Answer (score 5):

You can try this one...

`Shift + V` to enter in Visual mode

Then press `j` until you reach the text you want to be ident.

Finally press
`=`, it will ident automatically your selected code.

If you want to ident the whole code just type `gg=G`.

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is to select a bunch of lines and apply indentation only on them

You can apply indentation to certain lines in Visual mode. To do this follow these steps:

1. Position your cursor in the first line to be indented
2. Enter visual mode by typing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>
3. Move down, typing <kbd>j</kbd> until you reach the last line to be indented (alternately you can type <kbd>line #</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> if you know the line number of the last line to be indented).
4. Type <kbd>></kbd>

Another solution is to do this with a regex in command-line mode:

```
2,5s/\v(.*)/\t\1/g
```

Here the line range is specified in the first two numbers of the regex (in this case from line 2 to 5).

Comment: Step 4 either with > or with = will fail. As you see, > will just progress the cursor by 4 ( shiftwidth=4 ), wherein in the above example, only 3 additional spaces are needed ( because one space is already there )

Comment: @infoclogged I see your point, then you can use the regex: `2,5s/\v\s(.*)/\t\1/g`

Answer (score 0):

To answer both of your questions at the same time, you can use the `>` and `<` operators. Since they are *operators*, they behave just like `y`, `d`, `c`, and all the other operators do, so you must supply them with a motion. For example, `>>` will indent the current line (with 4 spaces), and `>j` will indent the current line *and the line below*. `>G` will indent everything to the end of the buffer, etc.

Similarly, `<` will unindent whatever you specify.

In your specific example, there are two different approaches I would recommend.

1. Use normal mode. This one kinda depends on how large your function is. If it's just the two lines, you could put your cursor on *line1*, and type `<j>,`. (Of course, if your function has more than 2 lines, you'll need to adjust). Unfortunately you need to unindent before reindenting because otherwise you'll end up with 5 spaces, which I assume you don't want.
2. Use visual mode. This one is slightly less convenient unless you modify your `.vimrc` because calling `>` or `<` in visual mode will drop your visual selection. That's why I have the following in my `.vimrc`:

   ```
   "Make it easier to indent a visual selection several times.
   xnoremap > >gv
   xnoremap < <gv
   ```

   With this setup, you can visually select the lines you would like to reindent, and then do `<>`. IMO, this is the best solution, and I frequently use this kind of workflow.

Comment: The part with unforunately in your point number 1 has lead me to ask this question. Is there no intelligent indenting in vim?  Eclipse has it and is intelligent to progress the cursor by 3 ( the boundary of multiples of 4 ) for example even if the shiftwidth is 4.

Answer (score 0):

Most (if not all) Ex commands take a range so you could just visually select the lines and do `:'<,'>retab`.

Or `:12,16retab`.

Or `:.,+9retab`.

And so on.

See `:help :retab` and `:help :range`.

Comment: I was wrong with retab in my question. Retab wont work at all in my line of code, because I have replaced the tabs with spaces using expandtab in .vimrc. The solution would be something like indent boundaries, but I dont think so vim has this. ( I have used this extensively in eclipse )